# Brainzilla Cryptic #2

Tags: letters

I have been doing the 'broken words' cryptic puzzles on the Brainzilla website, currently up to [the second puzzle](https://www.brainzilla.com/word-games/broken-words/cryptic/2/).

In this puzzle, you need to find words by combining the broken fragments listed. There are 35 fragments, used to make 9 different words and the theme linking them. Here are the fragments:

`RES  BIR  WIN  ENV  WER
OUO  DRA  CHE  ILE  OOR
ICE  NGA  THD  NEC  OFF
PES  COM  PUT  FRO  MSY
ENT  CKI  PEN  MED  ICI
ERF  ELO  DOW  ITE  ABI
NTD  AYP  NET  CCO  UNT`

So far, I have found the first, third, fourth, and fifth words. Could I have some help with finding the other words?

Comment: What is "brainzilla cryptic #2"? We can't solve your puzzle if we don't know what the puzzle is, and questions here should really be self-contained.

Comment: Are you referring to [this one](https://www.brainzilla.com/word-games/broken-words/cryptic/2/)?

Comment: Yes that website

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I'm glad you're eager to contribute here. Please do take a moment to compare what you originally posted here vs. how this question now appears. Questions that show the asker put in some effort to ask their question clearly and with all relevant information included tend to fare much better than those that don't. (At this point, some of these downvotes are probably unwarranted, but unfortunately your postings never get a second chance to make a first impression.) Please keep all this in mind when posting, and I hope you try sharing more puzzles in the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you just have to look for potential words when combining them and be aware some answers are more than one word. I was able to solve it on the website.

> [image: Answer screenshot]